# Merge files with same name in different folders

Tags: linux, while-loop, cat

I'm new to Linux and I'm looking for a command to merge files with the same name but from different folders. like this:

```
folder 1, folder l1

folder 1 contains folder 2 and files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, ... 

folder 2 contains files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, ...
```

I want to merge two texts from folder 1 and subfolder 2, then put them into folder l1.

I got this:

```
    ls ./1 | while read FILE; do

        cat ./1/"$FILE" ./1/2/"$FILE" >> ./l1/"$FILE"

    done
```

This one seems working well, two files are merged, however, a new empty file 2 is created in folder l1, and two pieces warning message on shell:
cat: ./1/2: Is a directory
cat: ./1/2/2: No such file or directory

I want to know explanations for new file 2 and warning message, more important how to improve the command line or new solutions because I have dozens of folder 1.

Comment: Can't you just change `ls ./1` to `ls ./1/2`?

Comment: yes, the changing works well.

Comment: yes, the changing works. There are several not-txt files in ./1/2, so I also got warnings saying no matched files found, however no new file is created. I guess no matched file generate the warning messages. I take the answer from codeforester whose modifying checks that file is matched or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks quite OK.  It is giving warnings because you are trying to merge directories as well!  You can add a check to skip over directories, like the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd 'folder 1'
for file in *.txt; do
  [[ ! -f $file ]] && continue      # pick up only regular files

  otherfile="folder 2/$file"
  [[ ! -f $otherfile ]] && continue # skip if there is no matching file in folder 2
  cat "$file" "$otherfile" > "folder l1/$file.merged"
done
```

It's important to quote the variables above to prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html).

Comment: Just updated the answer with explanation about why your code is throwing errors.