# Merge files with same name in more than 100 folders

Tags: bash, merge, cat

I have a problem similar to [Merge files with same name in different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864322/merge-files-with-same-name-in-different-folders), I have about 100 different folders in which there is a .txt file "replaced_txt", the problem is that I need to merge those files but since there is 100 different folders I want to know if tehre is something quicker than doing :

```
cat /folder1/replaced_txt /folder2/replaced_txt /folder3/replaced_txt ...
```

Comment: Quicker how? `cat /*/replaced_txt` is cretainly faster to type, but will not run any faster. `find -type f -name replaced_txt -exec cat {} +` will let you traverse arbitrarily nested subdirectories and avoid any  eArgument list too long" error, bqt might order the files unpredictably.

Comment: Thank you for your answer triplee, I was thinking to run faster. I tried 'cat /*/replaced_txt but it just make my pc crashed. I'll try the other solution you gave and let you know

Comment: A simple command like that should not crash a modern computer, though it can get slow on some systems if you have a lot of files in large directories.

Comment: I think mine is a bit old ... but I tried using "find -type f -name replaced_txt -exec cat {} +" and worked perfectly ! Thanks again :)

Comment: Even old computer should be able to handle 'cat */replaced_txt' without an issue. Can you clarify 'crash' ? Machine reboot ? Which Linux are you running ?

Comment: This might help: `cat /folder{1..100}/replaced_txt >new_txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cat` command is just about the simplest there is, so there is no obvious and portable way to make the copying of file contents any faster. The bottleneck is probably going to be finding the files, anyway, not in copying them. If indeed the files are all in subdirectories immediately below the root directory,

```sh
cat /*/replaced_txt >merged_txt
```

will expand the wildcard alphabetically (so `/folder10/replaced_txt` comes before `/folder2/replaced_txt`) but might run into "Argument list too long" and/or take a long time to expand the wildcard if some of these directories are large (especially on an older Linux system with an `ext3` filesystem, which doesn't scale to large directories very well). A more general solution is `find`, which is better at finding files in arbitrarily nested subdirectories, and won't run into "Argument list too long" because it never tries to assemble all the file names into an alphabetized list; instead, it just enumerates the files it finds as it traverses directories in whichever order the filesystem reports them, and creates a new `cat` process when the argument list fills up to the point where the system's `ARG_MAX` limit would be exceeded.

```sh
find / -type f -name replaced_txt -xdev -exec cat {} + >merged_txt
```

If you want to limit how far subdirectories will be traversed or you only want to visit some directories, look at the `find` man page for additional options.